# Fazer merge em CSV com Python

Tags: python, csv

Eu tenho uma coleção de dezenas de arquivos CSV. A maioria deles compartilha os mesmos campos, mas alguns têm campos exclusivos.
Eu quero fundi-los, usando Python em um arquivo CSV único com um cabeceamento global que inclua todos os campos de todas as colunas.
Eu estou usando a biblioteca CSV, mas até agora sem sucesso, porque os dados não terminam no lugar certo.

Comment: Poderia mostrar a parte do código que você salva os dados?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tive um problema similar algum tempo atrás. Ajustei um pouco para a suas necessidades. Poderá ter que mudar algumas coisas, nomeadamente ao nível do delimiter.

```
from glob import glob
import csv

"""
    este programa tem de ser excutado da directoria onde estão os csv.
    o output vai para o ficheiro consolidated.csv
"""
def create_global_header(files):
    """
        criar os cabeçalhos com todos os headers dos csv.
    """
    consolidated_header = ['filename']
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'r') as icsv:
            reader = csv.DictReader(icsv, dialect = 'excel', delimiter=';')
            for field in reader.fieldnames:
                if field not in consolidated_header:
                    consolidated_header.append(field)
    return consolidated_header

def global_csv(ifile, global_header, ofile):
    """
    le o ficheiro csv ifile, e bota para o ficheiro ofile.
    uma vez que o DictWriter e DictReader sao usados, e o cabeçalho
    é comum aos dois ficheiros, os dados sabem para que campo devem ir.
"""
    with open(ofile, 'a' ) as ocsv, open(ifile, 'r') as icsv:
        ireader = csv.DictReader(icsv, dialect='excel', delimiter=';' )
        owriter = csv.DictWriter(ocsv, global_header, dialect='excel', delimiter=';')
        for i, row in enumerate(ireader):
            row['filename']= ifile
            owriter.writerow(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = glob('*.csv')
    global_header = create_global_header(files)
    with open("consolidated.csv", 'w') as mycsv:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(mycsv, global_header, dialect='excel', delimiter=';')
        writer.writeheader()
    for file in files:
        if file != 'consolidated.csv':
            global_csv(file, global_header, 'consolidated.csv')
```